# Trying to replicate the elements in a list n times in OCaml

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, ocaml, tail-recursion

I'm trying to write a function that would take an input like :

> ```
> repeat 3 [1;2] ;;
> ```

and display something like:

> ```
> [1;2;1;2;1;2]
> ```

Now the code I have is:

```
let repeat ls n =
  let rec helper acc n l =
    if n = 0 then acc 
    else helper (l :: acc) (n-1) l 
  in
  let rec helper2 acc = function
    | [] -> acc
    | h :: t -> helper2 (helper acc n h) t  
  in 
  helper2 [] (List.rev ls);;
```

which gives me an output of:

```
[1;1;1;2;2;2]
```

for the same input. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You are almost at the end ;)

Just modify the first helper :

```
   let rec helper acc n l =
   if n = 0 then acc else helper (l @ acc) (n-1) l ;;
```

And you will be close to the solution.
(you just want to replicate the input list so @ is ok to concatenate this list to the acc, you do not want to parse each and every element of the list, so :: is not what you need)

Comment: Thank you for the response! I've tried that, but it changes the type of ls from  'a list  to 'a list list.. is there anything else I could try?

Comment: helper will be enough : helper [] 3 [1;2];; will yield [1;2;1;2;1;2] - that's it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think this solution may be a little bit faster in term of complexity (and simplicity):

```
let repeat ls n =
    let rec f l = function
        | 0 -> l
        | n -> f (List.rev_append ls l) (n-1) in
    List.rev (f [] n)
```

Also I always forget if `List.rev` is a tail-recursive or not, so this may be even better:

```
let repeat ls n =
    let rec rev l = function
        | [] -> l
        | a::t -> rev (a::l) t in
    let rec f l = function
        | 0 -> l
        | n -> f (List.rev_append ls l) (n-1) in
    rev [] (f [] n)
```

Note: in my opinion [Pierre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46259180/trying-to-replicate-the-elements-in-a-list-n-times-in-ocaml/46260540#46260540) is good enough, my post is more like remark.